# How do I use JQuery to access and loop through all drop-downs of a specific class?

Tags: jquery

Have a potentially infinite collection of drop downs, giving them all the same class, need to be able to access, loop through, and collect the selected value on the option of all the drop downs regardless of how many there could be. The final form should be something like 5,6,7,6,4,2,3,4,3,4 as a comma delimited list of the selected values from all drop downs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = $("select.classname > option:selected").map(function(n, i) {
  return $(n).val();
}).join(",");
```

To explain what that's doing:

1. Firstly it selects all the selected options within the given drop downs (identified by "classname");
2. It passes every selected option to a callback function;
3. That callback function returns the value of the selected option;
4. Because you called map on the array of selected options, you've now got an array of values using the `map()` method;
5. The [`join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function transforms that array into a comma delimited list.

For example:

```
<select class="classname">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Three</option>
</select>
<select class="classname">
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5" selected>Five</option>
</select>
```

first uses `$()` to construct a jQuery object of the selected options (2, 3 and 5), maps the value attributes into an array of `{2,3,5}` and then joins them into a comma-delimited string `"2,3,5"`.

Comment: can you explain what is happening here? whats up with the synatx inside the $()? I will loop up the .map thing on the jquery documentation... what is n and i?

Comment: woa - that is crazy... I still am having a hard time following one thing: when is the function being passed into .map() actually called? and how many times is it called? Otherwise this is making sense, that is pretty fancy.

Comment: The function passed into map() is a callback. It is called once per matched element. See http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer presented by cletus has two issues that needed to be addressed for my version of jQuery (1.6.2).  The code below worked correctly for me and alerts "3,5" when used against the sample HTML in cletus' post.  Note that it finds the *last* selected option and not *both* selected options from the first HTML select block.

```
var ids = $("select.classname > option:selected").map(function(n, i) { return $(i).val() } ).toArray().join(",");

alert(ids);
```

First, it was using the wrong argument within the map function call back.  I needed to change the **n** to **i** :  `return $(n).val()` vs `return $(i).val()`

Second, it was returning a jQuery object that needed to be converted into an Array before the array method 'join' could be used: `.toArray().join(",")`

Once those 2 minor modifications were made, cletus' answer worked perfectly for me in jQuery 1.6.2